# I am using bottom-tabs with a plus button But Plus button is not clickable in half of the area in react native in android Only?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, bottomtabs

[image]

I am using @react-navigation/bottom-tabs in the react native. And i need Plus button above the area, So i am able to achieve it, but in the Android Above half area of the Plus icon is not clickable in android.But in IOS it is working fine anybody have an answer about it.

Comment: the issue probably lies with `zIndex`. have you try setting a higher `zIndex`?

Comment: @kenmistry not working with zIndex

Comment: without code, it's gonna be hard to debug. Please attach some code to the question.

Comment: It's the same problem I've answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63578864/9098350, maybe my answer there is helpful to you. My answer uses a custom tab bar to solve the problem.

Comment: @PuneetKansal your central icon is absolute?

Comment: @PuneetKansal did you find the solution?

Comment: @AsifMushtaq Did you?

Comment: @NecmettinSargın Not Yet!

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use hitSlop property on your button like this to increase the tapping area:

```
hitSlop={{top: 20, bottom: 20, left: 50, right: 50}}
```